# Child fragment in View Pager Fragment disappears after swap

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So this is a bit of a complex question, but I will try to make it as easy to follow as possible.

To start, I have a main activity with a view pager. There are 2 pages in it, with 2 actionbar tabs linking each page.
I also have a drawer that has 4 options, the first 2 are the 2 pages in the view pager, and the second 2 are pages that aren't. If you select one of the second 2, I configured my ViewPager to swap out the fragments with 2 other ones. All of these fragments are singletons, so that switching back and forth doesn't cause any memory issues.

On switching to the second set of fragments, one of the fragments has a frame in it that I use to swap out child fragments when a button is selected. This is where the problem lies. After that fragment loads the first time, it works fine. But if you use the drawer to switch to the first set, and then back to the second again, the child fragment is gone. It then tends to crash after you do anything else after that.

This is the crash log for it

```
01-10 15:55:05.272: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21034): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
```

If I play around a bit with the code , I get something like this. These two errors are the ones I seem to produce the most:

```
01-10 16:00:13.072: E/AndroidRuntime(22227): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.ClassLoader android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getClassLoader()' on a null object reference
```

I can continue to call replace() on the frame view, so it's not going away. Therefore I'm guessing that's not the issue. It

Here is some relevant code for it.

The Fragment's code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator, container, false);
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    if(afFrag == null && topFrag == null){
        afFrag = CalculatorAfFragment.getInstance();
        topFrag = CalculatorTopFragment.getInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.calc_frame, afFrag, "afFrag").commit();
    }
    RadioGroup typeGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.type_buttons);        
    typeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.af_button){
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.calc_frame, afFrag, "afFrag").commit();
            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.top_button){
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.calc_frame, topFrag, "topFrag").commit();
            } 
        }
    });
    return view;
```

The FragmentStatePagerAdapter code:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(tools){
            return toolsFragmentsList.get(position);
        } else {
            return guidesFragmentsList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void swapFragments(int position){
        if (tools){
            tools = false;
            stores = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.setPrimaryItem(mPager, position-1, getItem(position - 1));
        } else {
            tools = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.setPrimaryItem(mPager, position-4, getItem(position - 4));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an error on call "getClassLoader()" so must be there where the problem is. Check that instance where you call "getClassLoader()" is completely initialize at this time.

Comment: please show more of the log in logcat, I find it strange that message is the most relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a unique ID on the `ViewPager` via `mPager.setId(View.generateViewId())`.